# crash on dynamic creating views fragment onresume android Galaxy Tab GT-P3100

Tags: android, facebook

I just want to ask why my app crashes with the following conditions.
I am working with fragments with only one activity. In my fragment, say FragmentA, I create views dynamically (inflating them). They work fine. But when I press home button, and go to the app again, I expect that FragmentA will be displayed but unfortunately, it throws NullPointer.
There is no errors in my android phone[GingerBread] but on my Tab, this error happens. Any help will be higly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing enough information to reliably answer this question, but the difference your're seeing is probably related to different behaviour of the garbage collector on the two different devices. As they are running on two different devices they will also behave differently.

The null-pointer you are seeing I would guess stems from wrongful use of member variables in your fragment.

When you go to the home screen and back your fragment will (or more accurately *CAN*) be recreated. Read: destroyed and re-instantiated using the argument-less constructor.

So make sure your fragment(s) are properly saving any needed state in onSaveInstanceState and restore this information in OnCreate/OnCreateView or whatever you're using.